# How can you change the layer ordering of OpenStreetMap tiles?

Tags: openstreetmap, carto, mod-tile

I found this picture on the carto.com website and wondered how one can render tiles where the street and district names are above the data overlay. What are ways to achieve this?

I have the mod_tile Apache module. It would be cool if I could render it on the server but I have no idea where to start at the moment.

[image]

Comment: You have a lot of tags there. Questions are best when they have a narrow scope, perhaps limited to the technology you're already using.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I removed two tags. Currently, I have only set up a OpenStreetMap tile server with mapnik and mod_tile. I am open to use any technology that can achieve the behaviour described above.

Answer (score 1):

CARTO uses two different tiles for the basemap without labels and then another set of tiles for the labels. Your data layer should be load in between (aka "sandwitch").

- Basemap without labels:

  https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png
- Basemap only labels:

  https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png

You can check other basemap providers [here](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/).